# How to access value inside a jquery function to outside angular function?

Tags: jquery, angular

```
create{
   var view;
   $(".l_item").click(function(){
      view = this.value;
   });
   console.log(this.view);
}
```

This is my jquery function used to get the selected value of the I_item (array of list).after getting this value i need to use this value outside the function

But i get undefined value..so how to achieve this ? any help will be appreciated,

Answer (score 1):

Define Your Variable Outside click function then use that variable inside your test() method

```
$scope.view;
$(".l_item").click(function(){
  $scope.view = this.value;
});
```

Then you can access the view variable outside the click function but it will work

```
test(){
  console.log($scope.view);
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174387/discussion-on-answer-by-chellappan-v-how-to-access-value-inside-a-jquery-functio).

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned here the Angular Version which you are using here. So, I am providing you the logic in context to the angular 2. Please follow below steps:-

1) If the jquery is installed then write following piece of code to access jquery inside the component.

```
declare var $: any;
```

2) It is always a good practice to write all the jquery in some external JS file, instead of writing at component level. So I am assuming that you already have an external JS file which has a function test() inside it.

3) Now at component level, in order to access that function you need to write the following line of code

```
declare var test: any;
```

4) Now in case you want that test() function should return some value, then inside the JS file you need to return that value as follows:-

```
test(){
return "some value";
}
```

5) You can get the value from jquery function at component with the following line of code :-

```
var returnValue=test();
```

6) Do remember that your external js file should load after the main jquery file. You  can add external jquery file to the angular module by declaring it inside angularCLI.json as follows:-

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../src/assets/js/core/testmodule/customtest.js"
  ],
```

All the best.

Comment: i have only a simple jquery code to use, so i prefer to use that inside the component itself.                                                                                                            i install jquery and import it in the component as mentioned above .but still not get it..result is undefined                                                                                          so what i need to change in my code                                                                                 i am using angular5

Comment: Try to modify the code as follows. Pass event or e inside the function brackets as parameter and then use that parameter to fetch any value.

create{

   $(".l_item").click(function(el){
        var id = $(el).attr('id');
        alert(id);
   });

}

Comment: sorry i m not really understand the thing, i got value inside the jquery click function, it not get outside the function